# Regex find two characters in order, between others, ignoring punctuation

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to filter using regex in mySQL.

The field is a text field and I want to find all that match 'MD' or similar ('M.D.', 'M. D.', 'DDS, M.D.' etc.).

I do not want to accept those that contain M and D as a part of another acronym (e.g., 'DMD'). However 'DMD, M.D.' I *would* want to find.

Apologies if this is a simple task - I read through some regex tutorials and couldn't figure this out! Thanks.

---

**Update:**
With help from the suggestions I arrived at the following solution:

```
(\s|^)M\.?\s*D\.?
```

which works for all of my cases. The quotes in my questions were to indicate it was a string, they are not a part of the string.

Comment: Pete if your question is solved, please marke it as resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I found this solution works:

```
(\s|^)M\.?\s*D\.?(\s|$)
```

This allows for the 'MD' to be at the start or after another credential and to have spaces or periods or nothing between the letters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like this:

```
\b(M\.?\s*D\.?|D\.?\s*D\.?\s*S\.?)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/zB4mC2/3)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I used your solution, substituting `\.` with `\\.` and `\b` with `[[:<:]]` so that it works in mySQL; it becomes `[[:<:]](M\\.?\s*D\\.?)`. It's working mostly, but it is still matching 'O.M.D.' and 'D.M.D.', which I don't want. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @PeteLudlow you can use this regex instead `^(M\.?\s*D\.?|D\.?\s*D\.?\s*S\.?)$` **[working demo](https://regex101.com/r/zB4mC2/4)**. But you will lose `DMD, M.D.`

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your requirement:

```
'([^'.]*[ ,]*M[. ]*D[. ]*)'
```

this looks for MD preceded by space comma or ' separated by 0 or more dots & spaces, followed by '
it matches all the contents between the '' marks

test: https://regex101.com/r/oV2kV8/2